# Backbone.Marionette throwing error trying to use CollectionView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I am getting stuck on a pretty annoying issue and decided to look for help as the error is hard to figure out.

I have a Marionette Layout view in a single page application representing the panel that switches out.  I have it working fine until I try to add a CollectionView as a child of the layout.  I am doing something wrong but the error I get is not very helpful.

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function backbone.marionette.js:1240
Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend._initChildViewStorage backbone.marionette.js:1240
Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.constructor backbone.marionette.js:1014
child backbone.js:1531
Marionette.Layout.extend.initialize
```

I can't figure out what function I need to define in this case.

Here is my 'page' Layout (as it sits in the require wrapper)

```
    return Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: Template,
        className: "page",

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.collection = new DataSet();
            this.collection.fetch();                                        

            // ADD THE VIEW
            var dataview = new DrinkCollectionView( { collection:this.collection } );

            // SHOW THE VIEW
            this.content.show( dataview );

        },

        regions: {
            content: "#page-content"
        },

    });
```

This is my CollectionView I am trying to use.  I've boiled it down to the bare minimum to try to get this to work with no luck.

```
    return Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        collection: MyDataSet,
        itemView: MyItemView,
    });
```

I assume that I am doing something wrong with creating things in the init method but I am not sure what is the right way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
G

Comment: Have you succeed? I've got same error after updating Marionette from 1.2 to 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

How `mu is too short` said, is hard to say whats going on here. Anyway try to look if you define vars like `Template` before then you define Marionette.Layout, same on `Marionette.CollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I see:

1) Not really sure about your use-case of returning 'Marionette.Layout.extend'
Assume that you will create an object using 'new' later?
Meaning that you should have the equivalent of

```
var MyLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend {...}
var _myLayout = new MyLayout ();
```

2) The region should be rendered inside 'onRender' instead:

```
onRender: function() {
  // SHOW THE VIEW
  this.content.show( new DrinkCollectionView( { collection:this.collection } ) );

}
```